# Is this a logic error or what happens? Problem with foreach

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a function in c that runs on a Postgresql server called get_ndistinct that returns the statistical value of get_ndistinct for the columns of some tables in a Postgresql database.
The fact is that when the foreach is entered twice, the second time, the value loaded in idxcd-> varattnames [i] appears to me as a number, when in fact I should return a column name value. And the number that appears to me matches the value that is returned for get_ndistinct in the previous step of the cycle¿? I really thought a lot and I don't understand why this happens. I don't know if it's a logic error of mine or what's happening. It's very strange, especially since the number coincides with the value returned in the previous step of the cycle ... that I don't know where or how it is loaded in idxcd-> varattnombre [i]¿?
To use a debugger, I don't know if I can ... because I use a Makefile. I don't know if I can use debugger with Makefile, I'm new using Linux.
I will greatly appreciate an answer please.
My source code is as follows:

```
/**
 * get_distinct
 *      for every candidate get an entry into IndexCandidate
 */
static List*
get_ndistinct( List* candidates )
{
    int proc;
    StringInfoData  query;  /* string for Query */
    StringInfoData  cols;   /* string for Columns */
    Oid             advise_oid;
    ListCell        *cell;
    IndexCandidate* idxcd;


    elog( DEBUG3, "IND ADV: get_distinct: ENTER" );



    initStringInfo( &query );
    initStringInfo( &cols );

    foreach( cell, candidates ) /* foreach cell in candidates */
    {
        idxcd = (IndexCandidate*)lfirst( cell );

        if (idxcd == NULL) {
            elog( INFO, "idxcd IS NULL" );
            continue; /* Or is that fatal enough to break instead? */
        }

        if (!idxcd->idxused)
            continue;

        int i;


        /* pfree() the memory allocated for the previous candidate. FIXME: Avoid
         * meddling with the internals of a StringInfo, and try to use an API.
         */
        if( cols.len > 0 )
        {
            initStringInfo(&cols);
        } /*IF col.len>0*/

        if( query.len > 0 )
        {
            initStringInfo(&query);
        } /*IF col.len>0*/


        appendStringInfo( &query, "select n_distinct from pg_stats where ");

        for (i = 0; i < idxcd->ncols; ++i)
        {


            appendStringInfo( &cols, "%s attname='%s'", (i>0?" OR":""), idxcd->varattnombres[i]);


        }/* foreach col in varattno*/


        /* FIXME: Mention the column names explicitly after the table name. */
        appendStringInfo( &query, "%s;", cols.data);



        if( query.len > 0 ) /* if we generated any SQL */
        {

            if( SPI_connect() == SPI_OK_CONNECT )
            {

                if( SPI_execute( query.data, true, 0 ) != SPI_OK_SELECT )
                        elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_execute failed while select." );

                else /* SPI_OK_SELECT*/
                {

                    proc=SPI_processed;
                    TupleDesc tupdesc=SPI_tuptable->tupdesc;
                    SPITupleTable *tuptable=SPI_tuptable;
                    char buf[8192];
                    int i,j;
                    for(j=0;j<proc;j++)
                    {
                        /*cada fila*/
                        HeapTuple tuple=tuptable->vals[j];
                        for (i=1,buf[0]=0;i<=tupdesc->natts;i++)
                        {
                            /* cada columna de cada fila*/
                            char *data;
                            data=SPI_getvalue(tuple,tupdesc,i);
                            idxcd->ndistinct[j]=data;

                            snprintf(buf+strlen(buf),sizeof(buf)-strlen(buf),"%s %s",data,(i==tupdesc->natts)?"": "|");
                        }

                        elog(INFO,"EXECQ:%s",buf);  


                    }

                }


                if( SPI_finish() != SPI_OK_FINISH )

                    elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_finish failed while select." );
            }
            else /* SPI_connect() != SPI_OK_CONNECT*/
                elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_connect failed while select." );
        } /*if( query.len > 0 ) if we generated any SQL */

    } /* foreach cell in candidates */          

        /* TODO: Propose to -hackers to introduce API to free a StringInfoData . */
        if ( query.len > 0 )
            pfree( query.data );

    elog( DEBUG3, "IND ADV: select: EXIT" );
    return candidates;
}
```

Comment: A makefile has nothing to do with a debugger. A makefile controls how the executable file is built. A debugger steps through the code at runtime. One has nothing to do with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the provided information it is impossible to pinpoint the error. Since the `foreach` loops through the list passed to your function, it depends on the caller of your function what values are in the list. Maybe you should start looking there.

About attaching a debugger, which is unrelated to a `Makefile`:

- Make sure that you compile with the `-g` option. This happens automatically if you configured PostgreSQL `--enable-debug`.
- Put a `sleep(10)` at the beginning of your function.
- Start a PostgreSQL session and use `SELECT pg_backend_pid();` to get the backend process ID.
- Call your function and quickly attach the debugger with

  ```
  gdb /path/to/postgres 12345
  ```

  where 12345 is the backend process ID.

Comment: The problem was that I was printing the value of idxcd-> varattnombres [i] as an integer value, with%d, when in fact I had to print it as a string value, with %s, that's why I was printing numerical values.

Comment: Great to hear that you are making progress developing and debugging PostgreSQL code. I know from my own experience that embarrassingly trivial errors can baffle you for days.